# What's the best way to prevent a proc reenry in Tcl?

Tags: concurrency, tcl, semaphore

Does Tcl have something like semaphores? I need to prevent reentry of a certain procedure. Something like this would work most of the time:

```
set inside_A 0
proc A {} {
    global inside_A
    if { $inside_A } {
        return "Ouch!"
    }
    incr inside_A
    ...
    incr inside_A -1
}
```

However, this is not reliable because the block check and increment are not atomic. Does Tcl have something like a semaphore to reliably prevent reentry?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent a recursive call of the function? Or just one that can only be called once period?

Comment: @Shawn, this functions is indirectly invoked from GUI, and with fast enough sequence of clicks gets invoked concurrently, which it certainly shouldn't do according to the application logic. I have no control over the clicks; my only recourse is to reject re-entry.

Answer (score 1):

Each Tcl interp runs in a single thread. So there is no possibility for anything to call your proc A between the check and the increment. This means that the method you outlined is safe.

In fact, there is nothing that can call proc A, unless it allows that to happen by calling a proc that may call back into A, by yielding if running as a coroutine, or by running update. The latter option is generally bad design that should be avoided, if at all possible.

When A is running as a coroutine, special care must be taken. The coroutine may be restarted, which would prevent the final decrement from ever running. That would make it impossible to ever call A again.

Comment: If you make two coroutines that call the same procedure, that procedure's not going to have reentrancy problems unless it is doing something with global variables that doesn't take kindly to such use. The procedure calls have independent local variables.

Comment: My coroutine remark was about starting a coroutine with the same name as one that is currently running. That would delete the old coroutine, depriving it of a chance to finish proc A.

Comment: @SchelteBron, alas, this is not the case. This particular Tcl interpreter is a part of a Qt application that allows concurrency (and, in fact, thrives on it). The interpreter object must be unique. 99% of the time this is not a problem, but once in a blue moon the same non-reentrant procedure is being hit twice. Thus the question.

Comment: Then that application is doing things that are at odds with the design principles of Tcl. I suspect that can cause much worse problems than running a non-reentrant procedure twice, because Tcl wasn't made to work that way. And obviously Tcl doesn't have protection methods for things that should not be possible.

Comment: BTW, folks, found out that `if { [incr my_semaphore]  > 1 }` does the trick.